# Parsing a multiline bracket-wrapped JSON file in Logstash

Tags: logstash, config

I'm trying to parse JSON logs being generated from a system in the form of:

```
[{"name" : "test1", "state" : "success"},
{"name" : "test2", "state" : "fail"},
{"name" : "test3", "state" : "success"}]
```

This is a valid JSON file however I am not able to parse it using the json filter.
My current **logstash.config** file looks like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/elastic_stack/json_stream/*.json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
    }
}
filter{
    mutate  {
        gsub => [ "message","\]",""]
        gsub => [ "message","\[",""]
        gsub => [ "message","\},","}"]
    }
    json{
        source=> "message"
    }
}
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstashindex"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I have tried adding a bunch of regex filters with gsub but since I'm pretty new I'm not sure if that's the cleanest and most efficient parsing solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: I could not reproduce, your config worked fine for me, it parsed the json without any errors. Can you share what is the output you are getting using only the `stdout` output?

Comment: @leandrojmp it is working however i just want to know if there's a better way